# How many ways to check if a script was "successful" by using Powershell?

Tags: powershell, backup, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am still very new and I have for example one script to backup some folders by zipping and copying them to a newly created folder.

Now I want to know if the zip and copy process was successful, by successful i mean if my computer zipped and copied it. I don't want to check the content, so I assume that my script took the right folders and zipped them.
Here is my script :

```
$backupversion = "1.65"
# declare variables for zip 
$folder = "C:\com\services" , "C:\com\www"
$destPath  = "C:\com\backup\$backupversion\"

# Create Folder for the zipped services

New-Item -ItemType directory -Path "$destPath"

#Define zip function


    function create-7zip{
    param([String] $folder, 
    [String] $destinationFilePath)
    write-host $folder $destinationFilePath
    [string]$pathToZipExe = "C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip\7zG.exe";
    [Array]$arguments = "a", "-tzip", "$destinationFilePath", "$folder";
    & $pathToZipExe $arguments;
    }

        Get-ChildItem $folder | ? { $_.PSIsContainer} | % {
     write-host $_.BaseName $_.Name;
     $dest= [System.String]::Concat($destPath,$_.Name,".zip");
     (create-7zip $_.FullName $dest)
     }
```

Now I can either check if in the parentfolder is a newly created folder by time. 
Or i can check if there are zip folders in my subfolders I created.

What way would you suggest? I probably just know this ways, but there are a million way to do this.
Whats your idea? The only rule is , that powershell should be used.

thanks in advance

Comment: Are you just wanting to check if any errors happened during the zip funciton?

Comment: either that, or check if my files are copied.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try using the `Try and Catch` method by wrapping the `(create-7zip $_.FullName $dest)` with a try and then catch any errors:

```
Try{ (create-7zip $_.FullName $dest) }
Catch{ Write-Host $error[0] }
```

This will `Try` the function `create-7zip` and write any the errors that many accrue to the shell.

Comment: `try..catch` only catches terminating errors. Also, external programs normally don't raise catchable errors. You need to evaluate `$LastExitCode`.

Answer (score 2):

One thing that can be tried is checking the $? variable for the status of the command.

$? stores the status of the last command run,

So for

```
create-7zip $_.FullName $dest
```

If you then echo out `$?` you will see either true or false.

Another option is the [$error variable](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/05/12/powershell-error-handling-and-why-you-should-care.aspx)

You can also combine these in all sorts of ways (Or with the exception handling).

For example, run your command

```
foreach-object {
create-7zip $_.FullName $dest
if (!$?) {"$_.FullName $ErrorVariable" | out-file Errors.txt}
}
```

That script is more pseudocode for ideas than working code, but it should at least get you close to using it!

Comment: You’re `If` loop logic is incorrect. `$?` is true when there are no errors on the previous command. So you will want the opposite: `If(!$?){#Error}"`.